# Do you think I can put road bike handlebars to this bike?

Tags: road-bike, handlebars, new-rider

Im new to bikes so I just want to ask a question. Is it possible to put a road bike handlebars on this bike. And if it is do I have to get a new stem also or just the handlebars?

[image]

Comment: It's certainly possible.  You might need a new stem.  And definitely new shifters.

Comment: ...and new brake levers too - long pull vs short pull may also require new brake calipers.  At this point its often more economical to replace the bike with a $50 used one, and transfer over any good parts.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that by 'road bars' you mean drop style handlebars.

You can replace the bars, but you will also need to find some drop bar brake lever / gear shifter units that work with the existing brake calipers and derailleurs.

Looks like someone fitted a riser bar and stem and some inexpensive twist shifters. We can't see if the derailleurs have been replaced as well. If you add info about the derailleurs (or pictures) we can provide more specific advice.

A drop bar bike would typically have a longer stem, so you will want to replace the current one. you can choose a stem length to get the riding position you want.

Comment: *Looks like someone fitted a riser bar and stem and some inexpensive twist shifters.* Yep.  And look how the saddle is shoved all the way forward.  That bike looks like it started with drop bars.

Comment: @AndrewHenle. Yep. I noticed the saddle and all the zip ties holding all the cables on. It's definitely a bit of a franken-bike now (no offense meant to the OP).

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus Should I try to make this bike somewhat good or just buy a new one?

Comment: @AndrewHenle If you want a decent bike that just works now, certainly you would be better off buying a new one. Even a inexpensive model will be more reliable and better to ride. There is likely a host of problems with this one beyond the bars and shifters

Comment: Ride it until it falls apart, maybe on rainy days, or unsafe for use. Invest the intended money into a decent new bike that fits your idea.